# In oracle SQL how to get todays date in the format of lets say 01-JAN-15?

Tags: sql, oracle

Just want to know In oracle SQL how to get todays date in the format of lets say 01-JAN-15?

So it should return 06-DEC-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_char()`.  This is how you convert dates to a string with any format you like:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

The explanation of the format is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510).